# Application didFinishLaunchingWithOption: detecting if app was launched after entering iBeacon region

Tags: ios, ibeacon, launching-application, region-monitoring

An app that **was not running** is launched by iOS when entering an iBeacon region. The first method called is **- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions**. As the launching reason can differ, I'd like to be able to detect from the launching **options** if the launch was due to entering a specific (the one I was monitoring for) iBeacon region or not. Is this possible?

I've found the following from the ApplicationDelegate documentation but I am not convinced that is the right one as it has no direct mention of iBeacons.

> **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey** The presence of this
>   key indicates that the app previously had one or more CBCentralManager
>   objects and was relaunched by the Bluetooth system to continue actions
>   associated with those objects. The value of this key is an NSArray
>   object containing one or more NSString objects.
>
> Each string in the array represents the restoration identifier for a
>   central manager object. This is the same string you assigned to the
>   CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey key when you initialized
>   the central manager object previously. The system provides the
>   restoration identifiers only for central managers that had active or
>   pending peripheral connections or were scanning for peripherals.
>
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see if a beacon detection launched your app, check for the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`.  This won't tell you which `CLBeaconRegion` entry launched your app.  For that you must wait for a subsequent `didEnterRegion` and check the passed value.

Comment: Thanks, that's brillant.